# How do I solve this without using a scientific calculator: $3-x^2 = 2^x$

Tags: exponential-function

Is there any way to solve the equation $3-x^2 = 2^x$ without using the calculator to estimate the solution for you? So far I've tried changing the base of the right hand side to base $e$ so $3-x^2 = e^{x\ln2}$ ,but the equation still cant be isolated for x?
$$\frac{\ln(3-x^2)}{x} = \ln2$$
Am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: $y=3-x^2$ and $y=2^x$ can be drawn using a graphing tool. By inspection one can see that $x=1$ is a solution. There is another solution too, but that one is "ugly".Without any devices, I am not aware that you can algebraically manipulate your equation to arrive at those two solutions.

Comment: @imranfat: The required manipulation is very straightforward. One of the solutions will of course be expressed in terms of one or more logarithms of specific numbers, but that's fine.

Comment: If that is allowed, sure then that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean $3-x^2$ or $3^{-x^2}$ on the left?  imranfat's comment solves one version, Brian Scott's answer the other.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan it is 3 - [x^2] Sorry, but I do not know how to format it like you did

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\ln 3^{-x^2}=-x^2\ln 3$, and $\ln 2^x=x\ln 2$. Let $a=\ln 3$ and $b=\ln 2$; then after taking the natural log on both sides you have $-ax^2=bx$. Can you solve that for $x$?

Once you've found its solutions in terms of the constants $a$ and $b$, you can always substitute the correct numbers for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Beat me on that one, but can you explain $\ln e^{-x^2}=-x^2\ln 3$?

Comment: isnt ln [e^(-(x^2))] = -(x^2) only but u said its equals -(x^2)ln3 ?

Comment: @imranfat: It was a typo.

Comment: In general, $\ln(a)^b = b\ln(a)$.

Comment: @Prandals: That was a typo; I'm on a mobile device at the moment and hit the wrong spot.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see. Thank you